# Unable to negotiate with server when running ssh pass in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm having this issue with ansible. My goal is to run the following command :

````
      ```sshpass -p {{ pass }} sftp -r {{ user }} @sftp.server.com:srcdir/* targetdir```
    
      ```sshpass -p {{ pass }} sftp -r {{ user }} @sftp.server.com:srcdir/* targetdir``` 

user@sftp.server.com:srcdir/* targetdir
Connected to sftp.server.com

Fetching ....

Fetching ....

Fetching ....
````

It works when I run the command but when I use ansible to do it, it fails with the following error:

ansible -m shell -a 'sshpass -p {{ pass }} sftp -r {{ user }} @sftp.server.com:srcdir/* targetdir ' test
test | FAILED | rc=255 >>
Unable to negotiate with IP port 22: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer non-zero return code

My sshd config file has the right config

```
ssh -Q mac
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
hmac-ripemd160
hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com
umac-64-etm@openssh.com
umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

Is there any reason why this fails on ansible? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, it turned out that the MACs are really missing to some of my host and I added them and that fixed the issue